# Problems with Delphi XE2, DataSnap and Lookup Field

Tags: delphi, field, lookup, datasnap

I have a bit of problem here. I have created a lookupfield in my application server using Delphi XE2 DataSnap technology. On the client side, that field becomes TStringField. Now, the problem is that I loose the lookup functionality on the client side. To top that, I can't change the stringfield on the client side because it is read only (even if I manually turn off the read only property).

I don't want to lookup tables on the client side because I don't want all the data loaded on my client side just to support look up.

I can change the Key field value, but the stringfield lookup text doesnt change unless I apply updates and reload the data.

Users want to see the text change.

What should I do?

Comment: How are you able to write to a lookup field in a normal (non-DataSnap) app?

Comment: non DataSnap is a simple. You create a lookup field and that's all. However, with Datasnap, its a different matter all together (as explained above).

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have to review your GUI functionality: lookup fields are really an client side feature. And it needs the **lookup source** - so to use it on client the lookup table must be loaded. DataSnap guys are very nice here, converting it to an TStringField when transmitting it to the client... I would simply ignore it.

So, if the lookup table is that big, you shouldn't using lookup fields but search UIs - or autocomplete comboboxes which you do queries against the DataSnap Server. Maybe you have to code it manually in the combobox case, I don't know (see if JVCL have something you can use to shortcut the path).

Alternatively, if the lookup table are seldom updated, you can aggresively cache it and have an updating mechanism to detect changes. So you can use the lookup fields the way they were created for.

Comment: Hey Fabricio, that makes me happy and sad at the same time! Anyway, here's what I have done. I have let gone of the Lookup field. Instead I created a Calc field on the client side. On calc, I call the a server function that looksup the value I need to based on the client's data. works quite well actually. It is 'patchy' I guess but what can you do. :-)

Comment: Lookup fields is a feature that make configuring lookup controls easier - but is no different of what an TDbLookupComboBox works. It needs an origin datasource and a lookup datasource. It takes a field (an 'Key') value from origin and searches the linking field (the 'Lookup key') on lookup source and, if found, shows the value of another field (the 'Display' field) on the lookupfield. There's no more magic about this. ;-) By the way, you'll accept this answer? ;-)

Comment: I did exactly that. I wrote a function that takes tablename, fieldname, fieldvalue and returnfield name. The only problem, it makes a call to the server everytime the calc field event is called but the load is negligible. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago i faced that problem and i found a solution that is a bit complex to analyze here but i try to give some guidelines till i have the time to write a detailed blog post.
The idea consists of info (concerning lookup fields such as field properties, datasets, providers) packaged by the provider as optionalparams at the server side. 
At client side a **derived** TClientDataset can unpack and process these info, create on the fly client datasets that retrieve needed lookup datasets and setup it's lookup fields accordingly.
The process is transparent due to the embedded functionality in the derived client dataset class and the only things to remember is to create that info in the provider's OnGetDatasetProperties event and turn false all provider flags in lookup fields.

Comment: I written the blog post and published the library. Here it is:

“LookCDS”, a small library set of functions, classes and components for Delphi that enables and utilizes at client side the lookup fields defined in a datasnap remote module.
http://g-vavoulogiannis.blogspot.com/2012/02/datasnap-transparent-client-lookup.html